# vlcj giving error on setting NativeLibrary path on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: javafx, media, jna, vlcj

I am trying to create a MediaPlayer using vlcj and javaFx which can play media file in browser as well as desktop.

I created a application which is running in windows but when I am trying to run this on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.1 I am facing issue getting error with setting NativeLibrary Path of vlcj. The code which I am using is

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), resourcePath);
```

And error which I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "Loading Resource in Background" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:79)
    at testinbrowserfxml.model.resource.RunResourceInBackgroud.addPassedVlcResourceBasedOnPlatform(RunResourceInBackgroud.java:219)
    at testinbrowserfxml.model.resource.RunResourceInBackgroud.run(RunResourceInBackgroud.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jna.tmpdir" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1298)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:708)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.getTempDir(Native.java:995)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.removeTemporaryFiles(Native.java:1018)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:677)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:129)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Your app doesn't have sufficient security permissions to read the `jna.tmpdir` property.  Likely the security settings on your OSX system are different than what they were on windows.

Comment: I have the same issues. Have you solved this?